# Posting a key-value pair through php cURL and finding the match on the server

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

When the user logs in, I want to send this user id and the password to the server through a php cURL request and return true if the key value pair matches correctly in the database.

Comment: Guessing you want to send it to 3rd party server... Since you're mentioning db, I'm also guessing you have access to this server. If so, then why not simply doing it via php you'll be using to parse input from POST and create curl request... Then again, that's too much guessing. Improve your question.